# Custom CircularProgressIndicator for Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'd like to make a custom CircularProgressIndicator to have gradient, elevation and rounded corners, but I couldn't find any libs with that ability. Could you please share your favourites or any workaround? It doesn't need to be animated, just a static progress bar to receive progress value and show it, example:
[image: Shadows, rounded corners and gradient]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out this **package**:

[percent_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/percent_indicator)

```html
CircularPercentIndicator(
    radius: screenWidth / 4, 
    lineWidth: 5.0, 
    percent: 0.75, 
    center: new Text("75%", style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF535355))), 
    linearGradient: LinearGradient(begin: Alignment.topRight,end:Alignment.bottomLeft, colors: <Color>    [Color(0xFF1AB600),Color(0xFF6DD400)]),rotateLinearGradient: true, circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.round)
```

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't add a shadow to it yet, but the final result is:

new CircularPercentIndicator(radius: screenWidth / 4, lineWidth: 5.0, percent: 0.75, center: new Text("75%", style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF535355))), linearGradient: LinearGradient(begin: Alignment.topRight, end: Alignment.bottomLeft, colors: <Color>[Color(0xFF1AB600),Color(0xFF6DD400)]),rotateLinearGradient: true, circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.round)

Answer (score 1):

```
CircularPercentIndicator(
    radius: 50.0, lineWidth: 10.0, percent: 0.4,
    circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.round,
    progressColor: Colors.purple,
    center: const Text(
        "10 min",
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16.0),
    ),
    circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.round,
    progressColor: Colors.purple,
),
```

Comment: Format the code for readability.